# Extremely simple test library

Tags: c++, testing

Is there easily embeddable C++ test lib with a friendly license? I would like a single header file. No `.cpp` files, no five petabytes of includes. So CppUnit and `Boost.Test` are out.

Basically all I want is to drop single file to project tree, include it and be able to write

```
 testEqual(a,b)
```

and see if it fail. I'd use `assert`, but it doesn't work in non-debug mode and can't print values of `a` and `b`, and before rewriting `assert` I'd rather search existing library.

Comment: If you're running tests, you probably want to compile in debug mode.

Comment: Have you tried defining `DEBUG` before including `assert.h`? Might work, not sure though.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, not always.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, it might trigger other #ifndef NDEBUG which I don't really want

Comment: @user1306239 you redefine `DEBUG` after the include, if it was defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm tempted to say "write your own", which is what I have done. On the other hand, you might want to reuse what I wrote: [test_util.hpp](https://bitbucket.org/maghoff/jsonxx/src/1923b4d9bd63/tests/test_util.hpp) and [test_util.cpp](https://bitbucket.org/maghoff/jsonxx/src/1923b4d9bd63/tests/test_util.cpp). It is straightforward to inline the one definition from the cpp file into the hpp file. MIT lisence. I have also pasted it into this answer, below.

This lets you write a test file like this:

```
#include "test_util.hpp"

bool test_one() {
    bool ok = true;

    CHECK_EQUAL(1, 1);

    return ok;
}

int main() {
    bool ok = true;

    ok &= test_one();

    // Alternatively, if you want better error reporting:
    ok &= EXEC(test_one);

    // ...

    return ok ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Browse around in the [tests](https://bitbucket.org/maghoff/jsonxx/src/1923b4d9bd63/tests) directory for more inspiration.

---

```
// By Magnus Hoff, from http://stackoverflow.com/a/9964394

#ifndef TEST_UTIL_HPP
#define TEST_UTIL_HPP

#include <iostream>

// The error messages are formatted like GCC's error messages, to allow an IDE
// to pick them up as error messages.
#define REPORT(msg) \
    std::cerr << __FILE__ << ':' << __LINE__ << ": error: " msg << std::endl;

#define CHECK_EQUAL(a, b) \
    if ((a) != (b)) { \
        REPORT( \
            "Failed test: " #a " == " #b " " \
            "(" << (a) << " != " << (b) << ')' \
        ) \
        ok = false; \
    }

static bool execute(bool(*f)(), const char* f_name) {
    bool result = f();
    if (!result) {
        std::cerr << "Test failed: " << f_name << std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}

#define EXEC(f) execute(f, #f)

#endif // TEST_UTIL_HPP
```

Comment: `bool`: the only type where `&= == &&=`

Answer (score 2):

Try google-test https://github.com/google/googletest/

it's really light weight, cross platform and simple.